# How to get auto generated id from Google Cloud DataStore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) says that I can omit the numeric id of an entity and DataStore will assign one automatically.

It however, does not say how to retrieve the auto generated id. How does one get it?

Is it available in the response or do I have to make a query against some other fields to retrieve the entity again just so I can see its ID?

Comment: Which language / ORM / Datastore library are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be in the corresponding `MutationResult` in the response. Here's a Python snippet that expands on [the one in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Creating_an_entity):

```
req = datastore.CommitRequest()
req.mode = datastore.CommitRequest.NON_TRANSACTIONAL
employee = req.mutation.insert_auto_id.add()

# Request insertion with automatic ID allocation
path_element = employee.key.path_element.add()
path_element.kind = 'Employee'

# ... set properties ...

resp = self.datastore.commit(req)

auto_id_key = resp.mutation_result.insert_auto_id_key[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **Node** library, the generated key is stored on a queried object with a [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). The datastore library exposes this symbol on `datastore.KEY`, and you can use it to access the id / key from an entity retrieved from the datastore:

```js
// Pseudocode -- you have a handle on the entity from prior list / create operation:
const myEntity = datastore.queryOrListOrCreate();

// actual usage to update it:
const key = myEntity[datastore.KEY];

console.log(JSON.stringify(key));
// prints something like: {"id":"5664922973241322","kind":"myEntity","path":["myEntity","5664922973241322"]}

// use it to e.g. udpate the entity
await datastore.save({
  key,
  data: myEntity,
});
```

The documentation does not explain this, so unsure if this is officially sanctioned.